# Getting sum of adjacent elements of a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have a matrix
eg.

```
[[4,5,0,0,0],
 [5,1,2,1,0],
 [0,2,3,2,0],
 [0,1,2,1,0],
 [0,0,0,0,0]]
```

For each element in the matrix, I am trying to get the sum of its adjacent diagonal elements and the sum of its adjacent horizontal and vertical elements.

Taking the 3 in the middle of the matrix for example, I am trying to calculate the sum of the diagonally adjacent elements (the 1's) and the horizontally and vertically adjacent elements (the 2's). 
For corner and edge cases, I want to disregard the areas where there are no elements eg.(for the 4 in the upper left, I'd want to get the sum of the diagonally adjacent 1 and the sum of the horizontally and vertically adjacent 5's.

What would be the most efficient way to do this in python?

So far i've come up with

```
diagonals = lambda x,y:[(x-1, y-1), (x-1,y+1), (x+1,y-1), (x+1,y+1)]
horiz_vert= lambda x,y:[(x,y+1), (x,y-1), (x+1,y), (x-1,y)]
```

to get the indices but these don't take into account the edge and corner cases.

Comment: Also if you don't use the wrong algorithm, the performance should not be too bad. Have you tried benchmarking?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The right tool to solve this task appears to be [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution). You only need to define the filters that will be applied in each position ("sum of diagonal neighbors" or "sum of vertical/horizontal neighbors") and you're done.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.signal

D = np.array([[4,5,0,0,0],
              [5,1,2,1,0],
              [0,2,3,2,0],
              [0,1,2,1,0],
              [0,0,0,0,0]])

h_diag = np.array([[1,0,1], [0,0,0], [1,0,1]])
h_hv   = np.array([[0,1,0], [1,0,1], [0,1,0]])
```

Here's how the filters look like:

```
>>> h_diag
array([[1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1]])
>>> h_hv
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0]])
```

You can think of 2D convolution as of shifting the filter across your matrix and calculating in each position the sum of the element-wise multiplication. Strictly speaking, the filters need to be mirrored, but in your case they are symmetric anyway. Here's a random illustration of the principle as found on the web:

[image]

The only difference to your case is that we want to place the filters everywhere, including the "boundary" or "corner" positions. This can be achieved by zero-padding the original matrix `D` such that the center of the filter can be placed e.g. in position `(0,0)`.

Good news! It's already implemented in Numpy/Scipy and it's a very efficient implementation! Now you just construct a matrix by convolving `D` with a filter `h`.

```
>>> scipy.signal.convolve2d(D, h_diag, mode='same')
array([[1, 7, 2, 2, 1],
       [7, 7, 9, 3, 2],
       [2, 9, 4, 4, 2],
       [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
       [1, 2, 2, 2, 1]])

>>> scipy.signal.convolve2d(D, h_hv, mode='same')
array([[10,  5,  7,  1,  0],
       [ 5, 14,  5,  4,  1],
       [ 7,  5,  8,  5,  2],
       [ 1,  4,  5,  4,  1],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  1,  0]])
```

From these matrices you can read off the required sums in each position. E.g. the central element in your original matrix `D`, i.e. `D[2,2]` is surrounded by 4 ones on the diagonals and 4 twos on the horizontal/vertical adjacency. The entries in the convolution output at the position `(2,2)` are therefore `4` and `8`. The position `D[0,0]` has only one diagonal neighbor (`1`) and two horizontal/vertical neighbors (`5` and `5`). The entries in the convolution output matrices are as expected `1` and `10`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_inbounds(x, y, length):
    return (0 <= x < length and 0 <= y < length)


def total_of_diags(m, x, y):
    size = len(m)
    return sum([(m[x - 1][y - 1]) * is_inbounds(x, y, size),
                (m[x - 1][y + 1] ) * is_inbounds(x, y, size),
                (m[x + 1][y - 1] ) * is_inbounds(x, y, size),
                (m[x + 1][y + 1] ) * is_inbounds(x, y, size)])
```

And now apply the same principle for the sum of adjacent numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def is_inside(x, y):
    return 0 <= x < len(m[0]) and 0 <= y < len(m) 

def diagonal_sum(x, y):
    return sum([m[x - 1][y - 1] if is_inside(x - 1, y - 1) else 0,
                m[x - 1][y + 1] if is_inside(x - 1, y + 1) else 0,
                m[x + 1][y - 1] if is_inside(x + 1, y - 1) else 0,
                m[x + 1][y + 1] if is_inside(x + 1, y + 1) else 0])

def vertical_sum(x, y):
    return sum([m[x][y - 1] if is_inside(x, y - 1) else 0,
                m[x][y + 1] if is_inside(x, y + 1) else 0,
                m[x - 1][y] if is_inside(x - 1, y) else 0,
                m[x + 1][y] if is_inside(x + 1, y) else 0])

m = [[4,5,0,0,0],
     [5,1,2,1,0],
     [0,2,3,2,0],
     [0,1,2,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0]]

diagonal = []
vertical = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    diagonal.append([])
    vertical.append([])
    for j in range(len(m[0])):
        diagonal[i].append(diagonal_sum(i, j))
        vertical[i].append(vertical_sum(i, j))

print(diagonal)
# prints:
#
# [[1, 7, 2, 2, 1],
#  [7, 7, 9, 3, 2],
#  [2, 9, 4, 4, 2],
#  [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
#  [1, 2, 2, 2, 1]]

print(vertical)
# prints:
#
# [[10, 5,  7, 1, 0],
#  [5, 14,  5, 4, 1],
#  [7,  5,  8, 5, 2],
#  [1,  4,  5, 4, 1],
#  [0,  1,  2, 1, 0]]
```

If you need the sum of the diagonals and verticals:

```py
def is_inside(x, y):
    return 0 <= x < len(m[0]) and 0 <= y < len(m) 

def neighbour_sum(x, y):
    r = 0
    for i in range(y - 1, y + 2):
        for j in range(x - 1, x + 2):
            if is_inside(i, j):
                r += m[i][j]
    return r

m = [[4,5,0,0,0],
     [5,1,2,1,0],
     [0,2,3,2,0],
     [0,1,2,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0]]

result = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    result.append([])
    for j in range(len(m[0])):
        result[i].append(neighbour_sum(i, j))

print(result)
# prints:
#
# [[15, 17,  9,  3,  1],
#  [17, 22, 16,  8,  3],
#  [9,  16, 15, 11,  4],
#  [3,   8, 11,  8,  3],
#  [1,   3,  4,  3,  1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the corner cases for a moment, one way to do this is to overlay shifted versions of the matrices atop one another.

For instance, given a matrix `m`, we sum over the *rows*:

```
def collapse_rows(m):
    # Select odd/even rows and then
    # pad top and bottom with row of zeroes
    e = np.pad(m[::2],  [(1,1), (0,0)], 'constant')
    o = np.pad(m[1::2], [(1,1), (0,0)], 'constant')

    # Sum together adjacent odd/even rows
    E = (e[:-1] + e[1:])[1:-1]
    O = (o[:-1] + o[1:])[1:-1]

    # Interweave rows
    m2 = np.empty((E.shape[0] + O.shape[0], m.shape[1]), dtype=m.dtype)
    m2[0::2] = E
    m2[1::2] = O

    return m2
```

Running this on your matrix, we obtain:

```
[[4, 7, 3, 2, 0],
 [5, 2, 4, 2, 0],
 [0, 2, 3, 2, 0]]
```

We can then do something similar for the *columns*. For speed, I suggest you specialize the code I wrote for rows, but I'm going to be lazy and do it on the transpose:

```
def collapse_columns(m):
    return collapse_rows(m.T).T
```

Running this on your matrix, we obtain:

```
[[4, 5, 0],
 [7, 2, 2],
 [3, 4, 3],
 [2, 2, 2],
 [0, 0, 0]]
```

Now we need to combine these matrices together. Let's shave off the extra rows/columns to produce 3x3 matrices, then sum them together:

```
result = collapse_rows(m)[:, 1:-1] + collapse_columns(m)[1:-1, :]

[[14,  5,  4],
 [ 5,  8,  5],
 [ 4,  5,  4]])
```

Just as desired!

...But how can we account for the boundaries? Simply pad your matrix with zeroes!

```
m_pad = np.pad(m, 1, 'constant')
result = collapse_rows(m_pad)[:, 1:-1] + collapse_columns(m_pad)[1:-1, :]
```

Which gives:

```
[[10,  5,  7,  1,  0],
 [ 5, 14,  5,  4,  1],
 [ 7,  5,  8,  5,  2],
 [ 1,  4,  5,  4,  1],
 [ 0,  1,  2,  1,  0]]
```

---

To sum diagonals, it's simply:

```
m_pad = np.pad(m, 1, 'constant')
result = collapse_columns(collapse_rows(m_pad))
```

Which produces:

```
[[1, 7, 2, 2, 1],
 [7, 7, 9, 3, 2],
 [2, 9, 4, 4, 2],
 [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I realized there's a much simpler way to do this than described in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48474988/365102).

```
def get_adj(m):
    m_pad = np.pad(m, 1, 'constant')

    x = m_pad[:, :-2] + m_pad[:, 2:]
    y = m_pad[:-2] + m_pad[2:]

    hv = x[1:-1] + y[1:-1]
    diag = y[:, :-2] + y[:, 2:]

    return hv, diag

print(*get_adj(
    [[4,5,0,0,0],
     [5,1,2,1,0],
     [0,2,3,2,0],
     [0,1,2,1,0],
     [0,0,0,0,0]]))
```

Results in:

```
[[10,  5,  7,  1,  0],
 [ 5, 14,  5,  4,  1],
 [ 7,  5,  8,  5,  2],
 [ 1,  4,  5,  4,  1],
 [ 0,  1,  2,  1,  0]]

[[1, 7, 2, 2, 1],
 [7, 7, 9, 3, 2],
 [2, 9, 4, 4, 2],
 [2, 3, 4, 3, 2],
 [1, 2, 2, 2, 1]]
```