# Python: how to reshape a dataframe by summing neighbour cells?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by

I have generated a dataframe `df` from a Matrix.

```
M=np.random.randint(10, size=(7, 5))
df = pd.DataFrame(M)
df  
        0   1   2   3   4
     0  8   3   2   2   5
     1  5   8   1   5   6
     2  1   9   1   4   2
     3  0   7   7   6   9
     4  5   8   7   0   9
     5  0   3   9   9   4
     6  7   7   8   5   4
```

I would like to generating a new dataframe `df1` by summing the neighboring cells `3x3` of `df`.

```
### Aggregate rows 0,1,2 and columns 0,1,2
df1[0][0] = [8+3+2+5+8+1+1+9+1] = 38
### Aggregate rows 0,1,2 and columns 2,3,4
df1[1][0] = [2+2+5+1+5+6+1+4+2] = 28

### Aggregate rows 2,3,4 and columns 0,1,2
df1[1][0] = [1+9+1+0+7+7+5+8+7] = 45
### Aggregate rows 2,3,4 and columns 2,3,4
df1[1][1] = [1+4+2+7+6+9+7+0+9] = 45

### Aggregate rows 4,5,6 and columns 0,1,2
df1[2][0] = [5+8+7+0+3+9+7+7+8] = 55
### Aggregate rows 4,5,6 and columns 2,3,4
df1[2][1] = [7+0+9+9+9+4+8+5+4] = 55


df1    
        0    1
    0  38   28
    1  45   45
    2  55   55
```

Comment: To clarify: every sum, you skip one row and one column?

Comment: @MarcusLim in my case I have a matrix 103 x 159 and I have to find a solution to aggregate the values. In this case every sum I skip two rows and two columsn

Comment: added tag numpy, I feel there should be some method for this.

Comment: Looks like a simple convolution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using convolution with [`convolve2d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) function in scipy :

```
M = np.random.randint(10, size=(7, 5))
print(M)

[[9 2 4 5 8]
 [4 0 3 4 9]
 [9 4 6 3 0]
 [4 6 9 9 5]
 [4 3 1 3 9]
 [9 2 9 0 7]
 [4 3 7 6 1]]


from scipy.signal import convolve2d

r = convolve2d(M, np.ones([3,3]), mode='same')[1::2,1::2]
print(r)

[[41. 42.]
 [46. 45.]
 [42. 43.]]
```

Here `np.ones([3,3])` generates the mask, 3x3 matrix of ones:

```
array([[1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1.]])
```

And I'm using [1::2, 1::2] indexing to start with element 1 instead of 0 and skip every other row/column like it's being done in the question.

Also see [Getting sum of adjacent elements of a matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48474308/getting-sum-of-adjacent-elements-of-a-matrix) for more info

Comment: this exactly what I was looking for. A question: why you have `np.ones([3,3])`?

Comment: `np.ones([3,3])` generates the mask, 3x3 matrix of 1's

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `df.shift`

```
axes = (0, 1)
shifts = -1, 1
intermediate_sum = (
    df
    + sum(df.shift(shift, axis=axis) for shift, axis in product(shifts, axes))
)
result = (
    intermediate_sum.dropna(how="all", axis=0)
    .dropna(how="all", axis=1)
    .iloc[::2, ::2]
)
result
```

> ```
>   1   3
> 1 23.0    22.0
> 3 35.0    33.0
> 5 18.0    18.0
> ```

Comment: I got the following: `AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1` when I try to compute `intermediate_sum`

Comment: Result differs from expected?

Comment: @RafaelC random numbers are generated, without setting a seed. See topline of OP.